# QGIS combine Vectorlayer and Rasterlayer to one shapefile

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, vector, matlab

I have to create some Thematic Maps, especially Choropleth Maps on Matlab.

Therefore i've found a shapefile which I can use, but need to draw some lines there.

I've imported my shapefile as a Vector Layer and my .jpeg file as a Raster layer and want to combine both to one shapefile.

I did "Polygonize" my Raster layer and combined both Vector layers to one shapefile, but it doesnt look the way as i want it.
Here are some screenshots:

My Vector Layer:
[image: Vector Layer]

My Raster layer:
[image: Raster Layer]

I want this result:
[image: Result]

Does anyone know, how I can achieve this result with this transparency?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve the desired result by going to your raster layer properties, pressing the plus (+) sign to add the deired color, and then setting the transparency percent:

[image]

You can see, in may example, how the raster target color transparency works:

- **Before** (no white color transparency / or the transparency percent for the white color = 100%)

[image: Look how]

- **After** (the transparency percent for the white color = 50%). You can see only the white color is affected

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks fine!

I'm curious, how can i save the vector and the raster layer to one shapefile? Haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Shapefile doesn't support rasters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the best thing would be to convert the raster to a polygon?

Comment: As Nathan said already, you cannot combine your layers into a shapefile. And if you are not satisfied with the solution proposed by me, you can also replace your raster with another two vector layers: one for the points in your raster, and one for the lines.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and best regards, I will see if I can achieve a good result with your solution.